# Из атласа в массив

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, pixijs, текстурный-атлас

Мне потребовался функционал атласов и нужно сделать так, чтобы у меня из любого атласа собирало массив спраитов с нужными мне именами и размерами если есть не стандартные атласы.

Допустим есть массив с атлаcами:

```
let atlases = {
    atlas1: {
        size: 25,
        width: 750,
        height: 300,
        sprite: {
            width: 146,
            height: 90,
            texture: '/images/atlas1.png'
        }
    }
};
```

То есть `atlas1` это картинка в папке `images`,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

остальные опции это:

`size` - количество спрайтов которые должны получится из атласа
`width` - ширина атласа
`height` - высота атласа

А во вложенном объекте `sprite`:

`width` - ширина получаемого спрайта
`height` - высота получаемого спрайта
`texture` - адрес до атласа со спрайтами

Я понимаю, когда они одного размера, но как же мне добиться результата, чтобы они могли быть разные.
Никак не могу додумать, что я делаю не так.

Пробовал делать так:

```
texture = new pixi.BaseTexture.from(texture.url);
for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    sprites.push(new pixi.Texture(texture, new pixi.Rectangle(i * Swidth, 0, Swidth, Sheight)));
}
```

Проблема вся в том, что я не пойму, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы я смог любой спрайт нужного размера вытащить из атласа.

По хорошему, чтобы можно было просто кинуть атлас и он чтобы разбирал сам на спрайты, любых размеров.
И запоминал его позицию и все размеры в массив.

Чтобы собирался из атласа, массив со спрайтами: где ключ это номер спрайта в атласе, а значение сам спрайт.

Вообщем не могу врубиться, как мне так сделать, чтобы я смог любую позицию на картинке выбирать или чтобы само раскладывала на нужные размеры и позиции...

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Comment: могу посоветовать обратиться в группы в телеграмме, https://t.me/webgl_ru и https://t.me/gamedevforweb, там часто обсуждают эти самые атласы из pixi.js и есть парочка коммитеров этого проекта

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да я понял как это делать нужно, там карта нужна для позиций, больше никак. Я сначала не понял, почему так, а потом дошло, там же когда пакуем в атлас, `json` фаилик собираем, вот он то и нужен.